# How to call python class from Servlet

Tags: java, python, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I have written a script in python which gets Top_25 movie list from IMDB database, I am creating a web application in JSP by which clicking on button "list movies" it should call the python script to generate all top_25 movies. I used runtime.exec() command to call python file but in the output I get nothing, empty console I get. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue i need to get output on web app after clicking button and if u know any better solution then calling python class from servlet please suggest that also.

JSP code:

```
<body>
<form action= "FirstServlet">
<table>
<tr>
<th>list all movies</th>

<td><input type ="submit" value = "list movies" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type ="text" name = "moviename" /></td>
<td><input type ="button" value ="search" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Servlet script:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //String searchTerm= request.getParameter("searchTerm");  

      //callPython.myMethod();//Call to java class method
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /Commutatus/movie_names.py");
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        // display each output line form python script
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(line);
        }

      //request.setAttribute("searchTerm",searchTerm);
      //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: have you got the solution for this?? @BleedCode